# How to provide specific Jfrog arifactory path in Jenkins groovy script for retention strategy

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, artifactory

I want to use specific artifactory path for log rotation strategy. We need to keep only 5 latest builds in the artifactory. We are successfully able to load jenkins build to the specified artifactory path, however we are unable to link the path to buildInfo variable for deletion/retention. If we don't specify path it doesn't throw error but it goes to some default directory and doesn't delete build from the path specified in the manifest. We cannot use CURL as artifact configuration is defined at admin level. So username and password needs to be picked from environment variable.

```
stage('Artifactory: Upload and retention') {
def server = Artifactory.server 'abc-xyz'
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()   

def upload_spec_bin = """{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "${cyncapp_binary_name}",
            "target": "generic-local/orgproj/cyncapp/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/"
        }
    ]
}"""
server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin

def upload_spec_manifest = """{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "cyncapp_manifest.txt",
            "target": "generic-local/orgproj/cyncapp/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/"
        }
    ]
}"""
server.upload spec: upload_spec_manifest

//def build_info = server.upload spec: upload_spec_manifest        
build_info.retention maxBuilds: 5,deleteBuildArtifacts: true        
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "path" in build-retention. The build retention should delete all artifacts of a build.
To make sure the build-retention deletes your build artifacts, make sure to attach them to the buildinfo object, during the upload phase:

```
...
server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin, buildInfo: buildInfo
...
server.upload spec: upload_spec_manifest, buildInfo: buildInfo
```

After the job is finished, I'd recommend checking the published module in the `builds` tab in Artifactory UI, and making sure all artifacts are there.

Read more about build retention here:

1. [Triggering build retention](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-TriggeringBuildRetention)
2. [Example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/vars-build-retention-example/Jenkinsfile)

Comment: stage('Artifactory: Upload') {
def server = Artifactory.server 'abc'
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo() 
buildInfo.env.capture = true
buildInfo.env.collect()
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 5,deleteBuildArtifacts: true
def upload_spec_bin = """{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "${cyncapp_binary_name}",
            "target": "generic-local/orgproj/cyncapp/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/"
        }
    ]
}"""
server.upload spec: upload_spec_bin, buildInfo: buildInfo
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 5,deleteBuildArtifacts: true        
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo

Comment: //Excerpt from Output Log
[consumer_0] Deploying artifact: http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8081/artifactory/generic-local/orgproj/cyncapp/76/abcd.bin
[Pipeline] publishBuildInfo
Deploying build info...
Build-info successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:8081/ui/builds/Aakash/76/1641732911875/published
Sending request for build retention, deleting build artifacts, max number of builds to store: 5.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: As you can see, the build is getting deployed in correct directory, however, request for deletion is sent in a different path.

Comment: I checked and it seems like the upload strategy is only applicable for JFrog Artifactory pro version and as we are using normal version, hence it is not working. I would suggest if someone could provide an alternative approach to implement the build retention strategy.